# Django serializer is_valid() returns True incorrectly

Tags: django, serialization

I'm having a problem where my serializer.is_valid() method is returning true even though the provided data in the serialization is incomplete. I have a simple model that looks like this:

```
class Dummy(models.Model):
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.TextField(max_length=128)
    organization = models.TextField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField()
    can_contact = models.BooleanField()
```

for which I have created the following serializer:

```
class DummySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dummy
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'organization', 'email',
                'can_contact',)
```

If I then run this test (note the lack of `can_contact` in the input serialization):

```
>>> serializer = DummySerializer(data = {'first_name': 'foo', 'last_name': 'bar', 'organization': 'quux inc', 'email': 'foo@example.com'})
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
```

If I were to attempt to save the serializer, I would get a constraint failure:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: demo_dummy.can_contact
```

It appears specifically to be the BooleanField; any of the other fields will be correctly recognized as missing. What is going wrong with the serializer, and what do I do about it, short of doing my own manual input validation?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why its working this way and I know you want to avoid manual input validation but this is a work around:

Add the following to your serializer depending on the version of django rest framework you have:

DRF v2:

```
def validate_can_contact(self, attrs, source):
    if source in attrs:
        return attrs
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Field Missing")
```

DRF v3:

```
def validate_can_contact(self, value):
    if 'can_contact' in value:
        return value
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Field Missing")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I tried it, but neither version of the method gets called. I can create custom validators for other field types, e.g. `validate_first_name` will get called (it uses the v3 calling convention). But `validate_can_contact` is not invoked.

Comment: Interesting...I tried adding `blank=False` to the model spec (so `can_contact = BooleanField(blank=False)`, and the validator then gets called, but the `value` parameter is `False`. Shouldn't it be `None` for a missing field?

Answer (score 0):

From Django [Boolean Field Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.BooleanField):

```
  The default value of BooleanField is None when Field.default isn’t defined.
```

Error given is:

```
  django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: demo_dummy.can_contact
```

DRF Model serializer is mapping field/attributes from Django Model.
So i think you must have to declare some default value for Boolean Field either True or False 
OR 
if you want to accept Null value then Change Boolean field to NullBooleanField

Comment: Changing it to NullBooleanField allows the `save` method to work properly, but it still fails to complain when the field is missing. I want `is_valid()` to return false if `can_contact` is not in the form data.